# How to add materialize css to an angularjs project?

Tags: css, angularjs, yeoman, materialize

I'm using Yeoman to develop a new site with angularJS. I've tried with `bower install materialize` and `bower install angular-material` but nothing happens, I mean, it doesn't change the appearance and functionality. I've add also to the index.html these two lines:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
```

I guess I may change the css route for the style, but not sure how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the line below to your head to load the css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css">
```

The full skeleton is available at

https://github.com/angular/bower-material/blob/master/README.md

By the way, your `bower install` and `script src` both refer to https://material.angularjs.org/latest and not http://materializecss.com/, which is in the title and tags. materializecss is a separate project that provides similar components. You probably don't need both.

Comment: Yes, you are right. There are two different projects, so I only use by now materializecss only. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`bower install angular-material --save`

This will install and (--save) update your package.json file.

when you make use of bower it will automatically update your index.html (add css and js files), you dont have to add any it manually.

In your case i would suggest you to check whether the dependency is added to your `app.js` or not, this could possibly be issue.

Comment: Thank you so much, I think I was confused by two different things: angular-material and materializecsss. I also checked the dependencies but the appareance didn't change anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party but I know how to do it with Angular Projects

**Angular 1.xx**

Simply import Materialise CSS in your project like this

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./js/cdn/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

     <!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
     <script src="./js/cdn/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="./js/cdn/angular-route.js"></script>
     <script src="./js/cdn/angular-animate.js"></script>

     <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="./js/cdn/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <!--Initalize MaterializeCSS-->
    <script src="./js/init.js"></script>
```

**Angular 2+**

First install materilize and Jquery

> npm install materialize-css jquery font-awesome --save

And then import Materialise CSS in `angular-cli.json` by simply copy paste below script and CSS paths

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
         "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
        "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
          "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
      ]
```

Include material icons in the `<head>` of `index.html` and you are good to go.

```
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice yeoman generator that will do that for you if you are starting a new project: https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular

just select it in the options after:

```
yo gulp-angular
```

For existing projects I just use the following repo:

https://github.com/angular/material#bower

which can be implemented by installing angular-material

```
bower install angular-material
```

Comment: btw, I see you are already trying to use angular-material. Can you check if  the 'ngMaterial' dependency was injected in your app? It could be that that's why nothing happens..

Comment: Yes I did and also I will try the yeoman generator you told me. Thanks!